# Find a continuous function $f$ such $\int_{a}^{a^2+1}f(x)dx=0\quad\forall a\in \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Find  example : exsits a nonzero continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ satisfying
$$\int_{a}^{a^2+1}f(x)dx=0\quad\forall a\in \Bbb R$$

the book answer this: $f(x)=x^2(x-1)(x-\frac{3}{5}),0\le x\le 1$,
$f(x)=-f(-x),-1\le x\le 0$.

$$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=0$$
But
$$\int_{1/2}^{5/4}f(x)dx\neq 0,a=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: You're right that the book answer doesn't make sense. Are you sure you're not missing something? The function you claim they give notably doesn't map R to R

Comment: If $b\ne a$ then $(b-a)^{-1}\int_a^bf(x) dx=(b-a)^{-1}\int_{a^2+1}^{b^2+1}f(x)  dx.$ Let $b\to a.$ Then $f(a)=2 a f(a^2+1)$. ...I dk what's next.

Comment: Okay, and what's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer you have is the seed of a full answer. You have a formula for $f$ on $[-1,1]$, but then you would need to use the defining relation to extend $f$ to larger and larger domains.

Take $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2(x-1)(x-\frac{3}{5})&0\le x\le 1
\end{cases}$$ where we know that with $a=0$, $$\int_0^1 x^2(x-1)(x-\frac{3}{5})=0$$

For $a\in(0,1]$, 
$$\begin{align}
\int_a^{1} x^2(x-1)\left(x-\frac{3}{5}\right)\,dx+\int_1^{a^2+1}f(x)\,dx&\equiv0\quad\text{(apply $\frac{d}{da}$ to both sides of this functional relation)} \\-a^2(a-1)\left(a-\frac{3}{5}\right)+f(a^2+1)\cdot2a&=0\\
f(a^2+1)&=\frac{a}{2}(a-1)\left(a-\frac{3}{5}\right)
\end{align}$$
So for $x\in(1,2]$, using $x=a^2+1$, you have $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{2}\left(\sqrt{x-1}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{x-1}-\frac{3}{5}\right)$$ and now you have a formula

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2(x-1)(x-\frac{3}{5})&0\le x\le 1\\
\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{2}\left(\sqrt{x-1}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{x-1}-\frac{3}{5}\right)&1<x\leq2
\end{cases}$$ that extends the book's answer to a larger domain. You can continue like this, extending the domain to $(2,5]$, then to $(5,26]$, and so on. For instance, the next extension gives
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2(x-1)(x-\frac{3}{5})&0\le x\le 1\\
\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{2}\left(\sqrt{x-1}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{x-1}-\frac{3}{5}\right)&1<x\leq2\\
\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x-1}-1}}{4\sqrt{x-1}}\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{x-1}-1}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{x-1}-1}-\frac{3}{5}\right)&2<x\leq5
\end{cases}$$

Once you've formalized this, check that everything is in order with negative input as well.

---

This reconciles with your example:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{1/2}^{5/4}f(x)\,dx&=\int_{1/2}^{1}x^2(x-1)(x-\frac{3}{5})\,dx+\int_{1}^{5/4}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{2}\left(\sqrt{x-1}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{x-1}-\frac{3}{5}\right)\,dx\\
&=\left[\frac{x^3}{5} -\frac{2 x^4}{5} + \frac{x^5}{5}\right]_{1/2}^1+\left[\frac{1}{5}\left((x-1)^{5/2}-2(x-1)^2+(x-1)^{3/2}\right)\right]_{1}^{5/4}\\
&=-\frac{1}{160}+\frac{1}{160}\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

For the information provided, the function $f(x)$ has to be zero if $f\in C^\infty$. Here is a sample proof.

Since $f(x)$ is a smooth function, it can be expanded with Taylor Series
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k\,x^k$$
And the integral is calculated as
\begin{align*}
\int_a^{a^2+1}f(x)\,dx&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k\int_a^{a^2+1} x^k\,dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{b_k}{k+1}\left[(a^2+1)^{k+1}-a^{k+1}\right]
\end{align*}

In addition, the term in the square bracket of above expression is definitely positive, because
\begin{align*}
(a^2+1)^n-a^n &= \sum_{i=0}^{n}C_n^ia^{2i}-a^n\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}C_n^ia^{2i}+a^{2n}-a^n+1\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}C_n^ia^{2i}+(a^n-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}>0
\end{align*}
for all $n\ge 1$, where $C_n^i$ is the binomial coefficient.

As a consequence, all $b_k$ has to be zero and $f(x)\equiv 0$.

But the discussion is limited to smooth $f(x)$, it is still open to special functions like Weierstrass function and etc.

Comment: The Taylor series of a smooth function need not converge to the smooth function, e.g. a bump function.

Comment: Asking for $f$ to be $C^{\infty}$ is a much narrower condition than the original question. Also, over $\mathbb{R}$, a $C^{\infty}$ function does not necessarily have a Taylor series which converges to it. The classic example is $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ with the hole filled in by declaring $f(0)=0$. This function is $C^{\infty}$, yet its Taylor series centered at $0$ converges to the $0$ function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the incorrectness of my statements. I have realized that both the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ and the bump function are smooth but cannot be expanded as Taylor series. The correct term should be analytic function. But it is too narrow to solve the origin problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the primitive $$F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)\>dt$$
of such an $f$. It has to be $C^1$, and has to satisfy
$$F(x^2+1)=F(x)\qquad \forall x\in{\mathbb R}\ .\tag{1}$$
Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq0}=(0,1,5,26,677,\ldots)$ recursively by
$$x_0:=0, \qquad x_{n+1}:=x_n^2+1\quad(n\geq0)\ .$$
Then $T:\>x\mapsto x^2+1$ maps the interval $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ bijectively onto $[x_{n+1},x_{n+2}]$ for each $n\geq0$. Choose a $C^1$-function $\phi:\>[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ which is $\equiv0$ in small neighborhoods of $0$ and $1$, and define $F(x)$ for $x\geq0$ recursively as follows:
$$F(x):=\phi(x)\quad (x_0\leq x\leq x_1),\qquad F(x):=F\bigl(\sqrt{x-1}\bigr)\quad(x_n\leq x\leq x_{n+1}, \ n\geq1)\ .$$
In this way $F$ is $C^1$ on all of ${\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$, and satisfies $(1)$ there. Finally put $F(x):=F(x^2+1)$ when $x<0$, and you have an $F$ fulfilling all requirements. The function $f:=F'$ then solves the original problem.